# compile qt-webkit with mingw32-make for bisecting

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, git-bisect

I started a bisect qtwebkit and when I try to compile it in the first stage it gave me the following exception. I tried using a older qmake but still it gives the same exception. What does this really mean and how can I fix it.

```
g++ -c -Wall -Wreturn-type -fno-strict-aliasing -Wcast-align -Wchar-subscripts -Wformat-security -Wreturn-type -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-switch -Wno-switch-enum -Wundef -Wmissing-noreturn -Winit-self -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DBUILDING_QT__=1 -DWTF_USE_ACCELERATED_COMPOSITING -DUSE_SYSTEM_MALLOC -DNDEBUG -D_HAS_TR1=0 -DBUILDING_QT__ -DBUILDING_JavaScriptCore -DBUILDING_WTF -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\..\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\..\include" -I"." -I"..\..\webkit" -I"assembler" -I"bytecode" -I"bytecompiler" -I"debugger" -I"interpreter" -I"jit" -I"parser" -I"pcre" -I"profiler" -I"runtime" -I"wtf" -I"wtf\symbian" -I"wtf\unicode" -I"yarr" -I"API" -I"ForwardingHeaders" -I"generated" -I"\include\QtWebKit" -I"pcre" -I"\JavaScriptCore\tmp" -I"..\..\..\..\include\ActiveQt" -I"tmp\moc\debug_shared" -I"c:\QtSDK1.2\mingw\include" -I"c:\QtSDK1.2\mingw\include" -I"..\..\..\..\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o tmp\obj\debug_shared\MainThreadQt.o wtf\qt\MainThreadQt.cpp In file included from wtf\qt\MainThreadQt.cpp:72:
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc:13:2: error: #error "This file was generated using the moc from 4.8.0. It"
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc:14:2: error: #error "cannot be used with the include files from this version of Qt."
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc:15:2: error: #error "(The moc has changed too much.)"
In file included from wtf\qt\MainThreadQt.cpp:72:
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc:42: error: no 'void WTF::MainThreadInvoker::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)' member function declared in class 'WTF::MainThreadInvoker'
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc:55: error: 'const QMetaObjectExtraData WTF::MainThreadInvoker::staticMetaObjectExtraData' is not a static member of 'class WTF::MainThreadInvoker'
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc:56: error: 'qt_static_metacall' was not declared in this scope
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc:57: error: too many initializers for 'const QMetaObjectExtraData'
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc:61: error: 'staticMetaObjectExtraData' was not declared in this scope
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc:62: error: too many initializers for 'QMetaObject::<anonymous struct>'
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc: In member function 'virtual int WTF::MainThreadInvoker::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':
tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc:88: error: 'qt_static_metacall' was not declared in this scope
mingw32-make[2]: *** [tmp/obj/debug_shared/MainThreadQt.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/Qt/qtGITSource/qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/JavaScriptCore'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug-all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Qt/qtGITSource/qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/JavaScriptCore'
mingw32-make: *** [sub-JavaScriptCore-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO ll. 2,3 is important:

> error "This file was generated using the moc from 4.8.0. It"
>
> error "cannot be used with the include files from this version of Qt."

Your reach a version less than qt 4.8 and all your moc-files were generated in a previous build by moc v4.8. You have to clean your build directory and restart your build command (ensure you use a proper version of qmake, moc etc.).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I did run mingw32-make confclean to clean the project but it did not seem to help me. In the error it mentions    tmp\moc\debug_shared/MainThreadQt.moc file but it does not exist. I also tried using qmake of 4.7.4. but it ended up giving me the same error. I really do appreciate your answer.

Comment: Which git commit of qt do you use? (Which commit causes this problem?) Do you compile on Windows or do you want to cross-compile?

Comment: I am using qt4.8 and trying to build backwards. I think I was doing it wrong there. I had to build it from the beginning rather than just building one component, which was qtwebkit.